# How to add animation on click of a image in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've developed a 'Web Page' I want to add animation when user clicks on arrow's image on web page. I want when user click on that arrow's image the div that going to open will open slowly not fastly that's what I want
Here is my code of html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.triangle_image').on('click', function() {
    $('.video').toggleClass('clicked');
    $('.triangle_image').toggleClass('clicked');

});
});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar_holder">
<div class="side_bar">
  <div class="ocean_logo"> <a href="#"><img src="images/ocean-group-logo.png" /></a> </div>
  <!-- .ocean_logo -->
  <div class="search_bar">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/serach_icon.png" /></a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH" />
  </div>
  <!-- .search_bar -->
  <div class="office_add">
    <h1>head office</h1>
    <p>BN-19(West)<br />
      shalimar bagh, delhi.<br />
      tel: <a href="tel:+91-11-32485885">+91-11-32485885</a></p>
    <br />
    <p>email:<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">info@oceangrouponline.com</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- .office_add -->
  <div class="social_icons"> <a href="#" class="fb_icon"><img src="images/updated_fb.png" /></a> <a href="#" class="twiter_icon"><img src="images/updated_twitter.png"</a> <a href="#" class="linked_icon"><img src="images/updated_linked.png" /></a> <a href="#" class="goggleplus_icon"><img src="images/updated_google-plus.png" /></a> </div>
  <!-- .social_icons -->
  </div>
<!-- .side_bar -->
   <div class="video">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qI0IW2prnaI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<h1>video description</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
<div class="visit_button">
<a href="#">visit more</a>
</div>
<div class="address">
<h1>ocean thermoplastic elastometer (p) ltd.</h1>
<div id="nav_link">
<ul>
<span class="nav_border">
<li><a href="#">wpc doors</a></li>
<li><a href="#">door frames</a></li>
<li><a href="#">decking</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cladding</a></li>
</span>
<li><a href="#">boards</a></li>
</ul>
<h1>woodtec</h1>
</div><!--#nav_link-->
</div>

</div><!--video-->





</div><!--.sidebar_holder-->

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="triangle"><img class="triangle_image" src="images/Untitled-1.png" /></div>
  <div class="woodtec_image1"> <a href="#"><img src="images/ocean-group-main-image.jpg" /></a></div>
  <div class="ocean_thermo">
    <h1>ocean thermoplastic elastometer (p) ltd.</h1>
    <p>innvotion planning and creation of products to meet the marketing strategies needs of the customer is of a job  of professional. continually working inclose  collabration with our customer , we have been able to build up professional based on the following philosopy of work.</p>
    <div class="visit_button"> <a href="#">visit site</a> </div>
    <!-- .visit_button -->
    <img src="images/ocean_triangle.png" />
  </div>
  <!-- .ocean_thermo -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="woodtec">
  <img src="images/ocean_triangle.png" />
    <ul>
      <span class="nav_border">
      <li><a href="#">wpc doors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">door frames</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">decking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">cladding</a></li>
      </span>
      <li><a href="#">boards</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>woodtec</h1>
    <p>"WOODTEC" is a brand  for WPC (wood plastic composite) products manufacture by ocean thermoplastic elastometer pvt ltd. having its plant in ghaziabad, delhi NCR and reach through out india.an indigenous brand which symbolizes innvoation and enviroment conservation is a leader in its category.</p>
    <div class="visit_button"><a href="#">visit site</a></div>
  </div>
  <!-- .woodtec -->
  <div class="woodtec_image2"><a href="#"><img class="hover_image2" src="images/woodtec-main-image.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
<!-- .wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

`here is my css`

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mexcellentregular';
    src: url('font/mexcellent_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/mexcellent_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/mexcellent_rg-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('font/mexcellent_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/mexcellent_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/mexcellent_rg-webfont.svg#mexcellentregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
}
.side_bar{    
    float: left;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.sidebar_holder{
    border-right: 18px solid #810304;
    background-color: #ffffd8;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 30px 22px;
    float:left;
    }

.video.clicked {
   display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #ffffd8;
    border-right: 20px solid #810303;
}
.triangle_image.clicked{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 530px;
    z-index: 99999;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ocean_logo{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.ocean_logo img{
max-width:100%;
}
.search_bar{
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 65px;
}
.search_bar a img{
    position:absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 9px;
}

.search_bar input[type="text"]{
    border: 2px solid #810303;
    line-height: 36px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 20px;
    background-color: #ffffd8;
}
.search_bar input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.office_add{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:40px;
}
.office_add h1{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#810304;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.office_add p{
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    color:#810304;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.office_add a{
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    color:#810304;
}
.social_icons{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
.wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url("images/background-image.png");
    padding: 6px 30px;
    width: 69%;
}
.triangle{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 389px;
    left: 348px;
    transition: width 10s;
    transition-duration: 5s;
}   
.woodtec_image1{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.woodtec_image1 img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
.ocean_thermo{
    float:left;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #ffffd8;
    text-align: center;
    width: 450px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 85px;
}
.ocean_thermo img{
    position:absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: -46px;
}
.ocean_thermo h1{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #000654;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #810303;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.ocean_thermo p{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #990000;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.visit_button{
    text-align: center;
}
.visit_button a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:#810303;
    color:#fff;
    }
.woodtec{
    float:left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #ffffd8;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position:relative;
}
.woodtec img{
    position:absolute;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    top: 135px;
    right: -42px;
}
.woodtec ul{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.woodtec li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;;
    font-size: 9px;
    color:#810303;
    font-family: arial regular;
}
.woodtec li {
    display: inline-block;

}
.woodtec h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 82px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #810303;
    font-weight: 300;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #810303;
}
.woodtec h1,
#nav_link h1{
     font-family: 'mexcellentregular';
}
.woodtec p{
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:left;
    ine-height: 18px;
    color:#810303;

}
.woodtec_image2{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 40px 0 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
}


}
.woodtec_image2 img{
    border-radius: 100%;
 }
.nav_border li a {
   border-right: 1px solid;
}
.video {
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
    display:none;
}
.video h1{
    display:lock;
    color:#810303;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
.video p{
    color:#810303;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.address h1{
    display:inline-block;
    color: #000654;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    border: 2px solid #810303;
}
.address {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}
.address ul{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.address li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;;
    font-size: 9px;
    color:#810303;
}
.address li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav_link{
    width:300px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #810303;
}
#nav_link h1{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #810303;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 45px;
}

img.hover_image2 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
img.hover_image2:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
```

`

Comment: Please give us only the related code, I don't know what's the element to be clicked too much stuff

Comment: do some google and read about jquery..you will find your answer..or else find any pre build theme..simple

Comment: try to focus on your question, looking at that amount of code ...

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery slidedown method

```
$( "div" ).slideDown( "slow" );
```

Answer (score 0):

to make the transition animated, you can add this rule to your css

```
.video
{
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```